# R - Narrow prediction intervals when forecasting with nnetar

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to build a forecast using the nnetar function from the forecast package. 
I get some fairly good forecast compared to other methods, but I am having trouble with it producing very narrow prediction intervals.

The dataset I am trying to forecast is weekly revenue data from an e-commerce with conversion rate and adspend as explanatory x variables (Xreg)

This is how my forecast looks like: 
[image]
This is the code I have used to produce it:

```
fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats = 200, xreg = xreg)
fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, h=26)
autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts$total)
```

This is the data I have used:

```
total_revenue_ts <- structure(c(429527.84912, 5107534.789265, 5334742.992202, 7062236.076739, 
7376937.2329, 8843885.679834, 10312889.001099, 4743025.186331, 
1063820.467744, 8647610.570788, 7615849.910587, 6950888.592508, 
6858879.08066, 7207686.138817, 6552543.847104, 6286320.862515, 
6387758.212579, 6267651.456223, 6166523.577491, 6517987.757523, 
4032163.322867, 6774882.672302, 7280882.606489, 7042888.802793, 
5864325.907872, 7614073.472534, 5702820.168872, 5993043.498666, 
5748712.530684, 5781854.779949, 6514731.488613, 6200435.741256, 
6716691.630149, 5671091.670532, 6849896.078633, 6412725.445233, 
5820498.437424, 5140661.371894, 5543105.774292, 6498649.993838, 
6832579.992745, 6363471.54561, 5764986.861829, 6479827.767348, 
6082916.613222, 5654806.062709, 6250723.443025, 7021696.610899, 
6878521.38167, 6605964.840134, 5860880.924163, 6027383.028358, 
7271275.876805, 5788375.978398, 5952319.104294, 8700792.56985, 
9387497.556219, 10628335.699833, 12300448.541447, 7624816.545391, 
8041602.838183, 7340912.745611, 6475830.912185, 6511598.406008, 
7670675.084654, 6597851.103698, 5992838.357045, 5782002.308393, 
7591927.838791, 6316308.891923, 6024260.46223, 6099526.226113, 
5341138.559686, 5959177.962052, 4614361.675905, 5649334.049846, 
6774789.19439, 7823320.381864, 5941416.816392, 6576822.658397, 
4949544.168466, 6394315.633561, 5432101.434962, 5971872.77196, 
6375234.021085, 6776885.612781, 6381300.2023, 5376238.120971, 
4654630.262986, 5404870.534346, 6616177.722868, 6627152.023493, 
6566693.385556, 6687236.645467, 6473086.938295, 5478904.979073, 
5884130.390298, 6219789.15664), .Tsp = c(2015.84615384615, 2017.71153846154, 
52), class = "ts")

xreg <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5723.69, 5528.78, 6099.31, 13001.39, 6750.07, 
6202.91, 6685.01, 5020, 5094.73, 2714.07, 9645.9, 8208.18, 6297.5, 
8053.29, 0, 4418.27, 9393.52, 11139.19, 12678.08, 12493.18, 11242.28, 
9617.09, 6959.37, 11716.52, 8464.61, 1499.14, 14538.86, 12080.69, 
11905.71, 14405.72, 9077.05, 10362.49, 13776.75, 17620.9, 14767.2, 
19511.98, 19747.72, 19885.44, 16810.46, 10618.04, 7494.02, 8166.45, 
7503.29, 7955.54, 7971.87, 14520.84, 19219.74, 18824.67, 27216.48, 
32030.82, 32007.76, 24153.88, 20472.33, 17617.01, 4.77806579193501, 
5.7287751461365, 5.28098389402001, 5.02434789173682, 4.95184840012426, 
5.64277441770686, 5.37984870432963, 5.3906432267007, 5.43849275673932, 
5.6884135855546, 5.2709838799333, 5.41075942817439, 4.94887009216008, 
4.95521307717827, 5.62734185585188, 5.51042637235732, 5.29807054480431, 
5.52756845275268, 5.70969961018115, 5.54781801299907, 5.73014260988972, 
5.99759204482959, 6.22750289793179, 5.93356463634027, 5.69127817622951, 
5.57154841999638, 5.66114857960352, 5.72923212265929, 5.31293510374571, 
5.35736716492903, 5.65568332596196, 5.74619318262752, 5.5954764989987, 
5.34701430785202, 5.38617886178862, 6.0341348094332, 5.46323395671082, 
5.33899929707969, 5.22135801253651, 5.65190410869423, 5.28112320474013, 
4.80649483723496, 4.81842452314323, 5.00675102835432, 4.49345845605863, 
3.82212461085761, 4.62551440329218, 3.79930173346953, 5.71101883613167, 
6.40135958079592, 7.1027311558873, 4.0456548762572, 4.86275624624909, 
3.68451118002285, 5.40269725877529, 5.24419134903069, 5.0344951706761, 
4.89131058216232, 5.63214154072982, 5.52286515754452, 4.99781361730586, 
5.09012974090091, 5.43346256247373, 5.20251523559131, 5.25889558131295, 
4.17869474160865, 5.59036205822923, 5.33376848927069, 5.38868363783592, 
5.43341024859593, 5.19857108205253, 5.19137882047327, 5.23814895237021, 
5.01957530659338, 5.48137535816619, 5.67523044227311, 5.26029025707068, 
5.18449109254837, 5.24915583751151, 5.45151430953043, 5.34584086799277, 
4.97336938233212, 5.22618004090631, 5.52619366814479, 5.70389182510811, 
5.75578084064244, 5.53339664450776, 5.16303263313334, 5.88409835642594, 
5.56461936196381, 5.20891730381574, 5.21675833063733, 5.30279468609766, 
5.22628072593614, 4.77056025260184, 4.72482746416563, 4.68623694730198, 
5.07214098963881), .Dim = c(98L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("adCost", "transactionsPerSession")), .Tsp = c(2015.84615384615, 
2017.71153846154, 52), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))

xreg_test <- structure(c(17617.01, 13526.88, 14836.89, 20358.16, 20416.79, 
21635.72, 15456.3, 12569.27, 18673, 20591.58, 18922.52, 19658.27, 
21371.37, 20921.06, 18846.68, 17315.48, 18569.47, 20276.32, 17932.33, 
18405.48, 17566.76, 15605.29, 18694.58, 17082.73, 18291.26, 18211.78, 
18252.98, 5.07214098963881, 4.9644513137558, 4.50735617759714, 
3.42940249666707, 5.57244242550868, 6.85297018333131, 8.27499041424656, 
5.64773791252811, 4.17746355274814, 4.78132627344352, 4.5212649754887, 
4.16629173040583, 3.95132622368061, 4.2603550295858, 4.07247936849659, 
3.98828918165935, 3.8364837584878, 4.32967453511229, 4.10479719434903, 
3.88986772076209, 3.89750505731625, 4.02224223511425, 4.23119830350054, 
3.54885240337703, 4.05530730967035, 4.46043036568541, 4.59654125314768
), .Dim = c(27L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("adCost", "transactionsPerSession"
)), .Tsp = c(2017.71153846154, 2018.21153846154, 52), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))

test_rev_ts$total <- structure(c(6219789.15664, 6207675.91913, 5375609.354946, 5970907.816396, 
4905889.954914, 6003436.003269, 6311734.743992, 5771009.21678, 
5284469.645259, 7228321.956032, 7070364.421462, 8978263.238038, 
11173150.908703, 8212310.181272, 5336736.750351, 6918492.690826, 
7807812.156676, 7025220.106499, 6539795.925754, 6734049.267568, 
6736165.004623, 5775402.314813, 6083716.578991, 6441420.211984, 
6269669.541568, 4968476.314634, 11122809.394872), .Tsp = c(2017.71153846154, 
2018.21153846154, 52), class = "ts")
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain why I am getting so narrow prediction intervals and how to solve it.

Comment: I have made similar observations about nnnetar any guess would be that this is so because these are not analytically derived prediction intervals but obtained by running a simulation of large number of forecasts. https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/nnetar-prediction-intervals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Why are the prediction intervals so narrow?*

By default, `nnetar` uses information from the *in-sample* residuals for the innovations used in prediction intervals. The residuals can be arbitrarily small depending on the complexity of your model. The [documentation gives this warning](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.3/topics/forecast.nnetar):

> Note that if the network is too complex and overfits the data, the
>   residuals can be arbitrarily small; if used for prediction interval
>   calculations, they could lead to misleadingly small values.

Related to that, your time series has 98 points and the model has 31 parameters. Furthermore, the data has a seasonal period of 52, and when using a seasonal lag you then effectively only have 46 data points to fit.

As a reference, the standard deviation of the `nnetar` residuals is roughly 4 times smaller than the residuals from `auto.arima`.

---

## *What to do about narrow prediction intervals?*

There are a couple possibilities. To speed up the computation of these examples I decreased the number of models fitted (to `repeats = 50`) and the number of PI simulations (to `npaths = 50`) from your example. To factor out effects from these changes and RNG, consider the model below as the baseline:

```
set.seed(1234)
fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg)
fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50)
autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
```

[image]

- ### Provide better innovations for `forecast` to use

  These will affect the intervals, but the mean forecast will remain the same.

  - #### Set innovations manually

    If you have some external knowledge of more appropriate innovations
    to use, you can provide them through the `innov` argument when
    forecasting.

    For example, say that you happen to know that the standard deviation
    of the innovations should really 3 times larger than what the
    residuals show. Then you can do:

    ```
    set.seed(1234) fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats
    = 50, xreg = xreg)
    ## Set up new innovations for PI 
    res_sd <- sd(residuals(fit_test), na.rm=T) 
    myinnovs <- rnorm(nrow(xreg_test)*50, mean=0, sd=res_sd*3)
    ## fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50, innov = myinnovs) 
    autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
    ```

    [image]
  - #### Use out-of-sample values

    You could estimate better innovations by using out-of-sample
    residuals rather than the in-sample ones. The `subset` argument in
    `nnetar` allows you to fit only part of the data. You could also use
    the [`CVar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.3/topics/CVar) function for cross-validation and grab the residuals from
    there. This is an example using the latter:

    ```
    set.seed(1234) 
    fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg)
    ## Set up new innovations for PI 
    fit_test_cv < CVar(total_revenue_ts,  size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg) 
    res_sd <- sd(fit_test_cv$residuals, na.rm=T) 
    myinnovs <- rnorm(nrow(xreg_test)*50, mean=0, sd=res_sd)
    ## 
    fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = reg_test, npaths = 50, innov = myinnovs) 
    autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
    ```

    [image]
- ### Control for overfitting

  These modifications will affect your model in addition to the prediction intervals, so the mean prediction will change compared to the baseline.

  - #### Drop the seasonal lag

    Your data has roughly 2 seasonal periods. Using a seasonal lag makes you lose a large fraction of it since the model needs the lagged values for fitting and forecasting. You could remove the seasonal component, perhaps adding extra lags to compensate. In the example below, by having more lags I'm increasing the number of parameters to 36, but "gaining" 49 points due to not having the seasonal lag.

    ```
    set.seed(1234)
    fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, p=3, P=0, size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg)
    fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50)
    autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
    ```

    [image]
  - #### Decrease the model complexity

    As mentioned before, with 5 neurons you have 31 parameters. Dropping that number to, say, `size=2` reduces the number of parameters to 13.

    ```
    set.seed(1234)
    fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 2, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg)
    fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50)
    autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
    ```

    [image]
  - #### Use regularization

    To compensate for model complexity, we can use the `decay` argument from `nnet` for regularization.

    ```
    set.seed(1234)
    fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg, decay = 1)
    fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50)
    autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
    ```

    [image]

    ---

## Bottom line

Several of these options can also be combined if appropriate for your uses, but at the end of the day it's important to keep in mind these are complex models and there's there's only so much you can do with ~100 data points.

Here's what a regularized model combined with out-of-sample residuals would look like:

```
set.seed(1234)
fit_test <- nnetar(total_revenue_ts, size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg, decay = 0.1)
## Set up new innovations for PI
fit_test_cv <- CVar(total_revenue_ts,  size = 5, repeats = 50, xreg = xreg, decay = 0.1)
res_sd <- sd(fit_test_cv$residuals, na.rm=T)
myinnovs <- rnorm(nrow(xreg_test)*50, mean=0, sd=res_sd)
##
fit_test_fc <- forecast(fit_test, PI=TRUE , xreg = xreg_test, npaths = 50, innov = myinnovs)
autoplot(fit_test_fc) + autolayer(test_rev_ts)
```

[image]

**Note that in the examples I assumed a normal distributions for the innovations and only varied the standard deviation, but they could just as well follow any other arbitrary distribution when manually adding them through the `innov` argument.